# Non existing blog pages are not redirected to 404

Tags: pagination, 404-error, blog-page

I've got a page called Blog. In the `Settings -> Reading` I've set my `Blog page` as `Posts page`. In the menu when I click on the `Blog` link the posts are loaded correctly and pagination works, so far so good. All the info is coming from the `home.php` template.

I'm using my own pagination code that generates the pages looking at `max_num_pages and paged` params. In short it generates correct amount of pages with the correct links.

However, when I test a non-existent blog page. For example there are 5 pages exist and I type `blog/page/6` it doesn't get redirected to 404, instead it seems to fall back to the else statement of the main `if(have_posts())`.

I've tested the category paginated pages that use the same pagination code, they work correctly: non existing category pages of type `category/<category_name>/page/2` are redirected to `404` template.

I can't think of anything why the main blog 'paged pages' that don't exist won't redirect to 404.

I would hugely appreciate any tips and help.

Many thanks,
Dasha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default Wordpress behaviour for pagination when using a custom query (where you feed in the paged value yourself) or in the index.php as it doesn't realize there isn't content to display on the XXXth page until it has already loaded the template, and then tries to run the WP_Query.

You can try adding logic that determines if $paged is set and no results are found, then throw the 404, which would look something like this:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
$wp_query->set_404();
require TEMPLATEPATH.'/404.php';
exit;
```

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed that it's a default WP behavior. Surely this is one of the top scenarios for a blog with a page being set up as "Posts Page". Gonna try your solution now. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I was wondering if the following statements do the same thing: `$wp_query->is_404 = true;` and `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->is_404 = true;` and `$wp_query->set_404();` Does it make difference which one to use? Similarly, are these the same as well: `status_header(404);` and `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");` and whether it makes difference to use them? Thanks!

Comment: This is **not** the default behavior. Try http://ma.tt/category/meta/page/20/ :D

Comment: @toscho, yes it somehow doesn't feel like a default behaviour.. It would be nice to know why that's happening. Hm, I'm not sure what I'm looking at at that link? :S

Comment: The link leads to a category page without posts. It's a 404 … because _that_ is the default behavior.

Comment: Yes, that's right, the category pages with non-existent page number gets redirected to 404. But not the main Blog non-existent pages.. Does that make sense? I've tried to describe it in the main question. I would thought it would be the same, but it doesn't seem to trigger 404 in the latter case.

Comment: Sorry I should've been more clear. It is the default behaviour when running a custom query, since you are feeding in the $paged variable yourself. If you let it use the default query behaviour for whatever template you are using (like a category page) then it should figure it out on its own.

Comment: After looking into it a bit more, it looks like it is also the default behaviour when running any kind of query in index.php

Comment: I'm using the 'standard' query for the blog, not custom. Also, my pagination doesn't do anything fancy, it constructs the same URL is prev/next entries using `get_pagenum_link()`. Thanks for looking at it more, it still feels strange that this is the default behaviour.. oh well.

Comment: The index.php is often used as a fallback, as it is the last template in the hierarchy for all of the Wordpress views.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that does makes sense. I'm guessing the `home.php` is similar in that sense then.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I usually use on my functions.php in every wordpress site (I know, I should code it as a plugin...)

```
/**
 * @author daniele raimondi W3B snc
 * @version 0.4
 * @abstract This workaround fixes a problem with page pagination, where you can request
 * n paginated part of a (non-paginated)page from 2 to 2147483647 (max 32 signed int value)
 * and you will never get a 404 error. WP returns instead the page itself  if it's a not-paginated page, 
 * or the first page if you request n-paginated pages, from n+1 on.
 */

function fix_missing_404_on_paginated_page() {
    global $wp_query,$page,$paged;

    if (!isset($page)) $page = get_query_var('page');
    if (!isset($paged)) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    if (is_page() || is_single()) {
        $realpagescount = count( explode( '<!--nextpage-->', $wp_query->post->post_content ) );

        if ( (isset($page) && isset($realpagescount) && $page >= $realpagescount) || (is_paged() && isset($paged) && $paged >=0 ) ){
        //wp_redirect( home_url() );
            nocache_headers();
            status_header( '404' );
            $wp_query->is_404=true;
            $wp_query->is_single=false;
            $wp_query->is_singular=false;
            $wp_query->post_count=0;
            $wp_query->page=0;
            $wp_query->query['page']='';
            $wp_query->query['posts']=array();
            $wp_query->query['post']=array();
            $wp_query->posts=array();
            $wp_query->post=array();
            $wp_query->queried_object=array();
            $wp_query->queried_object_id=0;
            locate_template('404.php', true);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'fix_missing_404_on_paginated_page');
```

Answer (score 2):

I had something similar recently on pages and posts in a multisite installation. Unfortunately I haven’t figured out *why* WordPress didn’t call the 404 template sometimes, but I build a workaround:

In the `functions.php` I created a small helper function:

```
/**
 * Helper for cases where the 404 template is not loaded correctly.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function t5_force_404()
{
    if ( have_posts() )
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    header( 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found' );
    locate_template( '404.php', TRUE, TRUE );
    $GLOBALS['wp_query']->is_404 = TRUE;
    return TRUE;
}
```

And on top of the `single.php` and `page.php` I called it like this:

```
if ( t5_force_404() ) {
    return; // stop any further processing
}

// everything is fine, go on.
get_header();
```

So … this will solve the issue, but I still don’t know why it happens.

Comment: This is a great approach to have a helper function like that, thanks!