# Stop wordpress to redirecting home page if no page found

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, 404-error

I don't want to redirect to home page when there is no page or wrong url. I have following in httaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml sitemap-%{SERVER_NAME}.xml [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml.gz sitemap-%{SERVER_NAME}.xml.gz [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]


# END WordPress
```

I have already 404.php in my theme folder. Let me know what to modify.

Comment: Do you have this problem with a [less modified `.htaccess` file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Creating_and_editing_.28.htaccess.29)?

Comment: Yes...I commented the above one, pasted and checked ...still persist.

Comment: You are better off renaming your existing `.htaccess` and letting WordPress generate a new one. Switch themes and disable your plugins. Ordinarily WordPress does not load the home page for 404s if there is a `404.php` in the theme. Do you have  live URL?

Comment: Thank for reply...I'll check ...live url: http://techbrij.com

Comment: I get `http://techbrij.com/cgi-sys/suspendedpage.cgi` and can't see anything else.

Comment: can you flush DNS or use Google DNS and open the site?

Comment: My Debian Squeeze box does use Google DNS.

Comment: Is it possible you have more than one `.htaccess` file? one in root and one in themes folder?

Comment: It quite possibly has nothing to do with your htaccess file but to do with how Wordpress loads templates depending on what URL you are testing it against. See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46116/non-existing-blog-pages-are-not-redirected-to-404 for more detail.